# Who is responsible for Avro Schema serialization in Kafka queue?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am learning the basics of Avro schema serialization. I understand that both, keys and values, can have their specific Avro schemas. However, what I am confused is how the serialization process actually works.

Do you specify the Avro schemas to use at the time of creating a topic? This way, the producer can post a message using plain json text and the kafka server knows how to serialize/deserialize it. Likewise, the consumer can obtain a record in plain json text.

Or, do you specify the schemas to use at the time of posting a message to a topic?

Finally, let's say I define my schemas in mykeyschema.avsc and myvalueschema.avsc. Would appreciate an example of how to use the schemas either from the command line kafka tools or as curl scripts (for rest proxy). Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using the Confluent Avro Schema Serializer and Deserializer with Schema Registry, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topics are independent of schemas; they do not (and often are not) defined together.

Most importantly, Kafka only knows about byte arrays; the clients decide serialization format. If you choose to pay for Confluent Server, for example, only then can you force Kafka to accept only Avro bytes (obviously, this adds latency to your requests because the records are being deserialized by the server to do the validation, but this is the trade-off for "protecting the topic from bad actors").

That being said, producers are the ones sending data. They often are responsible for registering the schema, based on what is sent. Consumers can then decide to use that schema or define their own projection of those fields (Avro requires both reader and writer schema for deserialization).

---

> example of how to use the schemas either from the command line kafka tools

```
kafka-avro-console-producer --topic foobar \
  --property value.schema="$(jq -rc < example-schema.avsc)" \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --sync
```

And rather than type out long JSON payloads, you can redirect JSON file with line-separated records into that

```
kafka-avro-console-producer ... < records.json
```

> REST Proxy

When you call POST requests to send data you can provide the key/value schema as JSON encoded values (not ideal since it makes every request much larger than necessary), or you can pre-register the schema, which returns an ID that you can use.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html

Comment: Thank you. On further digging, it appears you have to pass key_schema_id and value_schema_id to rest API. Looks like the rest proxy server will do proper serialization before inserting the record in the Kafka queue.

Comment: Using the REST Proxy you can both send the schema or the ID in the --data parameter. If you send the complete schema it will be registered automaticaly in the Schema Registry and it will return you the proper ID.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use the proxy. Updated with docs